# Handleing objects in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

What im trying to do is to create a method that can handle being given most things. like ArrayLists, or tables or even ArrayLists of tables.

```
static void print(Object solution) {
    String ClassString = solution.getClass().getName();
    System.out.println(ClassString);
    switch (ClassString) {
    case "String[]":

        for (String S : (String[]) solution) {
            System.out.print(S + " ");
        }
        break;
    case "java.util.ArrayList":



        String Name = ((ArrayList) solution).get(0).getClass().getName();


        switch (Name){
        case "java.lang.String":
            for(String item : ((ArrayList) solution)){

            }
            break;
        }


//          for(String[] S: AList){
//              print(S);
//          }

        break;

    }

}
```

the problem i have is that the `for(String item : ((ArrayList) solution))` gives the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String` in eclipse, what am i missing that makes all of this click

Comment: i did a google search, but it do not really help as i do not really know what im looking for

Comment: Writing such a “generic” function is almost certainly a bad idea in your case. Accept an abstract `Collection<T>` and don't fight the type system.

Comment: yeah ik its bad i just wanna try